# Azure Front Door log query table not found

Tags: azure, azure-front-door

After creating an Azure Front Door resource I attempted to run a preset query

```
// Requests to origin by route 
// Count number of requests for each route and origin per minute. Summarize number of requests per minute for each route and origin. 
AFDAccessLog 
| summarize RequestCount = count() by bin(TimeGenerated, 1m), Resource, RouteName, OriginName, ResourceId
```

but the `AFDAccessLog` has a red squiggly and I get an error `The name 'AFDAccessLog' does not refer to any known table, tabular variable or function.`

[image]

Even fter enabling diagnostic settings and sending all logs to a log workspace `AFDAccessLog` still does not resolve to anything.

If I use `AzureDiagnostics` then there is no problem.

Why is this included in the Front Door log preset if it does not work out of the box?

Comment: Searching the internet for "AFDAccessLog" & this is the only result. I hope someone from Azure sees this post

Answer (score 0):

Queries for Front Door are incorrect in the Queries example window.

They all start with AFDAccessLog as the table, but it doesn't exist.

Product documentation shows that you should call the AzureDiagnostics table and then filter to the Category you need (Below is only one such category)

| where ResourceProvider == "MICROSOFT.CDN" and Category == "FrontDoorWebApplicationFirewallLog"

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/web-application-firewall/afds/waf-front-door-monitor?pivots=front-door-standard-premium#access-logs

Here is an example of query that does work.  Notice the column names are different as well.

AzureDiagnostics
| where Category == 'FrontDoorAccessLog'
| summarize RequestCount = count() by clientIp_s, httpVersion_s, ResourceId
|top 10 by RequestCount

Finally, there wasn't a good docs pointer to GitHub that I could find specific to those queries.  Via the Azure portal, I submitted this same basic content.  Also, maybe this is useful to you.

https://github.com/microsoft/AzureMonitorCommunity/tree/master/Azure%20Services/Front%20Doors